# Using NFC with Mvx WP8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc, mvvmcross

I am attempting to use NFC in an Windows Phone 8 application, which uses the MvvmCross framework. Now normally you subscribe to receive NFC events on WP8 by adding an `Extension` to the `WMAppManifest.xml` like so:

```
<Extensions>
    <Protocol Name="my-resource" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskId="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

This will launch the `_default` task, if it finds a uri starting with `my-resource://`, which on a fresh project is the `MainPage.xaml`. In this case I have set it to `Views\ScanView.axml`, which is a `MvxPhonePage`.

Then to get the data in the `_default` task, you would override `OnNavigatedTo` and grab the `e.Uri`, which is the data from the NFC tag. I.e.: `/Protocol?encodedLaunchUri=my-resource://ni?EkkeEkkeEkkeEkkePtangyaZiiinngggggggNi`.

Now it seems that the `MvxPhonePage` overrides `OnNavigatedTo` on its own and uses it for some save states. So my question is. How do I get original Uri instead of the saved state?

Can I just work around it by using the `MainPage.axml` and then when I am done loading the NFC stuff navigate to `Views\ScanView.axml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a custom `AppStart` which is briefly described in this [Slide Deck](https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/appstart-in-mvvmcross), which Stuart Lodge told me to look at.

So in my `ScanViewModel` I added an `Init(string url)` method, which handles navigation with extra parameters, in this case my wanted Url, and then I can handle it as I want there.

In `App.xaml.cs` where you normally call the `Start()` method of the `AppStart` I added some conditions:

```
var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
var url = navigatingCancelEventArgs.Uri.ToString();
if(url.StartsWith(@"/Protocol?encodedLaunchUri=my-resource")
    start.Start(url.SubString("/Protocol?encodedLaunchUri=".Length));
else
    start.Start();
```

Then I had to create my own `AppStart`:

```
public class MyCustomAppStart : MvxNavigatingObject, IMvxAppStart
{
    public void Start(object hint = null)
    {
        if(hint is string)
            ShowViewModel<ScanViewModel>(new {url = (string)hint});
        else
            ShowViewModel<ScanViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Which I instantiate in the `MvxApplcation` `Initialize` method:

```
RegisterAppStart(new MyCustomAppStart());
```

Then I get the desired Url in `Init` in the ViewModel:

```
public void Init(string url)
{
    //Whatever I want, whatever I need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to define a custom `UriMapper` to catch and validate the external launch URI, and then return the URI of the actual page you want to launch. That way you keep the external launch logic away from your page navigation logic.

See [UriMapperBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.urimapperbase%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) docs for the basics. You'll need to add the `UriMapper` to your `PhoneApplicationFrame` at the correct point.

In App.xaml.cs:

```
// Do not add any additional code to this method
// ;)
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
        return;

    // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
    // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
    RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();

    // TODO: Add custom UriMapper here
    RootFrame.UriMapper = new MyCustomUriMapper();

    RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

    // ...
}
```